# Android php mysql connection error: FileNotFoundException

Tags: php, android, mysql, connection

there is my code to connect my android application to my database:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
        String reg_url = "http://192.168.1.23/info+/php/add_user.php";
        String method = voids[0];
        if(method.equals("register")){
            String fName = voids[1];
            String lName = voids[2];
            String phone = voids[3];
            String email = voids[4];
            String wilaya = voids[5];
            String sexe = voids[6];
            String age = voids[7];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(false);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("fName","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(fName,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("lName","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(lName,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("phone","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(phone,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("wilaya","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(wilaya,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("sexe","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(sexe,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(age,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                is.close();
                return "Registration success";

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

but I have an error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.23/info+/php/add_user.php

I don't why add_user.php is not found cause it exists in my project folder?

Comment: copy and paste link in browser does it open? my guess not

Comment: as @Gert said, the exception simply means no such file exists. Either your path is wrong or your web server is not running or the client and server are not in the same network

Comment: the link open in the browser but not in my phone

Comment: i found the solution devs;